# Web page appears on the half of ipad's screen

Tags: android, css, ipad, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

One of my recent works has some pretty strange bugs on the ipad. I don't own one, so my client took some screenshots for me. I am totally out of ideas.

The site is built with Twitter Bootstrap. You can find it here as well as all of the code:

http://www.webalys.com/

Here are the screenshots:

https://www.box.com/s/f45c618996c65006266a

On two of the images the site appears only on half of the screen in landscape mode.
Then if it doesn't do that there's some huge margin on both sides ( I think it's from the fixed layout we used ).

I played a lot with the viewport meta tag but with no luck. Whatever I do it looks bad either on the ipad or the iphon or on android phones. 
I added the viewport meta tag to avoid squishing all the text in one column to fit mobile displays.

And the strangest of them all is that if it's loaded from a google search, the site loads on one side and the search remains on the other.

I am not sure if I managed to explain clear enough.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I removed the meta "viewport" tag and it all worked correctly. The site loads without altering anything and the padding on the sides is gone.

My best guess is that it is unnecessary when one wants to preserve desktop look on smaller screens instead of going for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the bootstrap.responsive.css file, without that it won't resize.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css

Comment: Bootstrap is quite odd... when you download it it doesn't seem to include all the correct css files and javascript files. I must have done it wrong and I guess OP has too, but its not very clear. Also make sure that responsive.js is there too.

Comment: Yeah view the source and make sure you have the JS/CSS they do, or use the http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html page to make sure you get the stuff you need.

Comment: Yeah, I always view source on the examples to make sure I have the same as they have.

Comment: Well, I have specific instructions to keep the layout fixed size using the fixed grid. That is why I haven't included the responsive.css and js files. 

This explains the margins on one of the pictures for me, but I cannot see why it should appear on the half of the screen as it does.